# each() reaching only one element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I'm scrolling down to a point of my site and then I call an `each()` function to animate all numbers (4). However the `each()` function loops only once so only one number is animated.

```
var activated = 0;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var hT = $('#scroll-to-numbers').offset().top,
        hH = $('#scroll-to-numbers').outerHeight(),
        wH = $(window).height(),
        wS = $(this).scrollTop();

    if (wS > (hT + hH - wH)) {
        if (activated == 0) {
            activated = 1;
            animateNumbers();
        }     
    }
});

function animateNumbers(){
    $('#number-animate').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
        }, {
            duration: 9000,
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function (now) {
                $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col">
        <h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
        <p class="bodytext">
            <span id="animate-number">1998</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
        <p class="bodytext">
            <span id="animate-number">250</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
        <p class="bodytext">
            <span id="animate-number">15</span>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
        <p class="bodytext">
            <span id="animate-number">350</span>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique on document context...  Use class instead. And anyway in your posted code, the each loop is useless, most jQuery protoype method (setter) work on multiple elements in matched set, looping internally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, use CLASS instead ID in this case.

Other things, the .each() generally loop internally like explain by A.Wolff.

Let's try to change some of you HTML and some of your JS:

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col animate-number-wrapper">
    <h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
    <p class="bodytext">
        <span class="animate-number">1998</span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col animate-number-wrapper">
    <h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
    <p class="bodytext">
        <span class="animate-number">250</span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col animate-number-wrapper">
    <h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
    <p class="bodytext">
        <span class="animate-number">15</span>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="col animate-number-wrapper">
    <h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
    <p class="bodytext">
        <span class="animate-number">350</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

JS

```
function animateNumbers(){
   $('.animate-number-wrapper').each(function () {
     $elem = $(this).find('.animate-number');
     $elem.prop('Counter',0).animate({
        Counter:  $elem.text()
     }, {
        duration: 9000,
        easing: 'swing',
        step: function (now) {
             $elem.text(Math.ceil(now));
        }
    });
   });
}
```

Comment: Your html contains same id's please change them as this is accepted answer, and people will follow this. thank you.

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot. It was part of my answer but forgot to update part of code. Thank you! :D @Sudarshan

Answer (score 2):

Please try this fiddle, there were some changes needed to do like
 - a html doc can have only one id for doc
 - you have #scroll-to-top element mentioned in jquery but no where it was added in html

Here is working [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b5mmk1yk/)

Here is your html code, you can add scroll wherever you want, and also can change class names but please do change in js also.

```
<div class="row " id='scroll'>
<div class="col">
<h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
<p class="bodytext">
<span class="animate-number">1998</span>
</p>
</div>
<div class="col ">
<h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
<p class="bodytext">
<span class="animate-number">250</span>
</p>
</div>
<div class="col ">
<h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
<p class="bodytext">
<span class="animate-number">15</span>
</p>
</div>
<div class="col">
<h3 class="text-center">text</h3>
<p class="bodytext">
<span class="animate-number">350</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is js code

```
var activated = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
var hT = $('#scroll').offset().top,
    hH = $('#scroll').outerHeight(),
    wH = $(window).height(),
    wS = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (wS > (hT+hH-wH)){
        if(activated == 0)
        {
            activated = 1;
            animateNumbers();

        }     
    }
});
function animateNumbers(){
console.log('called');
    $('.bodytext>.animate-number').each(function () {

        $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
            Counter: $(this).text()
            }, {
                duration: 9000,
                easing: 'swing',
                step: function (now) {
                    $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                }
        });
    });
}
```

For better scrolling effect please try this [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ffq37vcc/)